# Adding components to a feature via Drush

Tags: drush, features

I understand using 'drush fu' to look for changes to any components of an existing feature, but is there a way to add a component to an existing feature using drush? Right now I have to use the /admin tools to recreate, download the files, upload, etc. Would be nice if there was a way to do this process via drush.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update:** there is a direct way to add components via Drush.

First, to list components `drush fc` (for *features components*) will list out all exportable components, including which, if any, feature they are currently exported to.

Next, `drush fe foo_feature variable:foo_var views_view:foo_view` will update, or create, a module named `foo_feature`. The output from `drush fc` can be used to populate the required `component:name` syntax.

**Original answer**

While there is no direct command, the quickest way to add components is by editing the `.info` file.

For example, to add a view `foo_view`, you would add this line:

```
features[views][] = "foo_view"
```

or, to add a variable that hadn't been added, you would add this line:

```
features[variable][] = "my_variable"
```

Once these have been added to the `.info` file, you can then run `drush fu`, and the additional components will be exported with your feature.

Update:

There *is* a command. See the below answer about the `drush fe` command.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with user permission and drush 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was unable to load the re-create page in the UI for one of my site's features, and the only way to update it or add new components is via drush fc / drush fu—and it's way faster besides, which is a win in my book.

Comment: does anyone have a drush command or anything to change the fc format to info file format ? BTW the " arent needed afaik

Answer (score 17):

There's been an on-going discussion about this topic, but it seems that drush features-export (drush fe) is the accepted solution.

To find the components (views, pages, etc.) you want to add to your feature, use `drush features-components`; this command has a relatively easy-to-use interface that should be familiar to anyone who has created Features through the admin graphical interface.

Once you've found the component you want, enter it in the pattern `drush fe [feature_name] [component_name]`, as in the following:

```
drush fe feature_name views_view:user_questions
```

#### HISTORICAL INFO (deprecated)

Drush formerly used `drush features-add` for this functionality; the maintainers seem to have settled upon `drush features-export`.

Comment: Interesting, that's cool.

Comment: Just to note that features add is deprecated. Use features-export instead.

Answer (score 4):

*drush features-add* is deprecated. Use *drush features-export* instead. It will add components to existing features as well.

To get a list of exportable components first use

```
drush features-components --not-exported [pattern]
```

See *drush features-components --help* for how to use *[pattern]* to filter the components to be listed.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that quotes are required for permissions that have spaces in them. For example `drush fe fcc_user_config user_permission:"edit own content_type content"`